# Chrome iOS not using retina background-image

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, background-image, retina-display

I'm on an iPhone 5... I started updating my website, to use retina images. Everything works perfectly in Safari. For some reason, my background-image for the `body` isn't using it, and its super blurry. Any ideas? Is this a bug? This is what I have for the media query for retina displays:

```
body {
    background: 
        url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat,
        url(style/images/dark/bg5.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat, 
        url(style/images/dark/bg5_repeater.png) repeat bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color:#09273e;
    color:#e4e4e4;
    background-position: 15px 10px, top, bottom;
}

@media 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {

    body, #header {
        background: url(../images/dark/bg5_repeater@2x.png) repeat;
        background-size: 70px 70px;
    }

}
```

Here is the link to the file and code line, on my bitbucket: http://bit.ly/Sxevfg

Here are some screenshots too between Safari and Chrome on iOS 7.1.1.

Thanks so much

[image: Chrome background-image]

[image: Safari background-image]

Comment: Just noticed the screenshots are pixelated when looking at this page, stackoverflow, on a mobile device LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that the image was not saved as a progressive image. When saved as progressive, it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome [renders pages with Safari's engine](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq#chrome-for-ios) (the only browser engine Apple allows on iOS), so this must be a difference between in-app Safari ([UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and actual Safari.

But my answer is that you should not be implementing a retina tax.  Are double-resolution images really worth doubling the user's mobile data usage, or doubling your page's load time?

(If work on the [Network Information API](http://www.w3.org/TR/netinfo-api/) continues, maybe we'll get media queries for bandwidth...)

Comment: Very interesting. My answer, yes it's worth it. Me as a designer, I notice crap like that. I hate blurry images. Guess it's fine then. Most people probably use Safari anyways. Thanks

Comment: FYI it's 4x the bandwidth. 10 X 10 = 100. 20 X 20 = 400.

Comment: It's not 4x the bandwidth - it varies. That only applies if the images are uncompressed.